Question chemistry aluminum electrolytic capacitors and storage electronic devices
What recommendation How to prevent deformation of the dielectric layers in aluminum electrolytic capacitors from stored electronic devices that were manufactured in the early 90s and early 2000s and store my home at a temperature of 33-36C, humidity 57-67% and energized devices at 220v AC 60hz?

I’m voting to close this question because it needs a pragmatic answer from an electronics expert. However the electrolytic capacitors that I've ordered always came uncharged, and with the terminals unconnected.

Prevent deformation (loss of oxide layer) now, after being stored for 30 years? A bit late.

These devices were not stored for 30 years without power. I said that they are devices manufactured in the 90s and 2000s. They were used with some frequency, so I acquired these devices and keep them stored in the conditions I mentioned.
